# Multi threading in C# (Parallel.For(), the Threading class or async and await)

Tags: c#, multithreading

### Introduction

Just out of curiosity, how can I make a multi threading loop where the order is guaranteed from low to high and `Console.WriteLine("Done");` has been executed after the loop has done. I've tried three cases explained below.

---

### Case one: `Parallel.For(...)`

If you will make a for loop that runs parallel in C#, you can use this code:

```cs
ParallelLoopResult result = Parallel.For(0, 10, i => 
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{i}, task: {Task.CurrentId}, Thread: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}";
    Thread.Sleep(10);
}

Console.WriteLine($"Is completed: {result.IsCompleted}";
```

This will give next output where the order is not guaranteed. You will see different results if you run the code once more. The run of the program has the order 0-2-4-6-8-... with five tasks and six threads.

```
0, task: 1, thread: 1
2, task: 2, thread: 3
4, task: 3, thread: 4
6, task: 4, thread: 5
8, task: 5, thread: 6
5, task: 3, thread: 4
7, task: 4, thread: 5
9, task: 5, thread: 6
3, task: 2, thread: 3
1, task: 1, thread: 1
Is completed: True
```

---

### Case two: the `Thread` class

I've also tried to use threading instead of the `Parallel` class. Here is the code:

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        Thread tr = new Thread(() => Print(i));
        tr.IsBackground = true;
        tr.Start();
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Done");
}

private static void Print(int i)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
    Thread.Sleep(10);
}
```

Following result of this code is now that the order isn't also guaranteed form low to high and the string `Done` has been written after the for loop end but not always guaranteed, however I've place `thread.Start();` after `Console.WriteLine("Done");`.

```
1
2
3
5
7
7
8
9
9
Done
```

Like in my second run:

```
2
3
3
4
5
6
7
8
Done
10
```

---

### Case tree: `async` and `await`

I'll also try this way, but I didn't know how I can implement this way of threading for a loop.

---

### Question

In all the cases I haven't the result I needed. In the first case was it not guaranteed to be ordered and in the second case has `Done` been written before the loop has run. So my question is how can I run a for loop where the order is always guaranteed and `Done` written after the loop has run?

Comment: `async`-`await`'s primary purpose isn't multithreading, it is avoiding the complexity of multithreading when performing I/O.

Comment: In general you can't rely on the order in which multiple threads execute. Why do you need the operations to be performed in a specific order? That might help answer your question better.

Comment: Your second example is not correct it only starts one thread, not 10(dependent on your environment) like your first example. Also if you want done to be at the end you need to wait for the thread to complete by using thread.Join(); after the start();

Comment: The requirement of the items to execute in a fixed order directly contradicts the requirement to perform the work in parallel.  You can do one or the other, but not both.

Comment: @Marko actually he does not need the `thread.Join()`, because he did `thread.IsBackground = false;` the thread will keep the program open until the thread finishes even if `Main()` has completed.

Comment: `Following result of this code is now that the order is guaranteed` That is false.  The order is in no way guaranteed.  You're just happening to the the items in order because it takes less time to do the work (as the "work" is only printing a value to the console) than it does to start up the next thread.  The second you do any non-trivial amount of work (or even if you don't, potentially) that won't be the case at all.  You've done nothing here to *guarantee* the order.

Comment: If you're multithreading, the order won't be guaranteed. That's the point.

Comment: @Servy: you've right, I've edit my question.

Comment: @Luïs The edit does nothing to address the problem.  You problem is right here: `how can I make a multi threading loop where the order is guaranteed`  The answer to that question is that you *can't*.  It's fundamentally impossible.

Comment: @Servy Is right, with a small but important addition: **You can**, but it requires synchronization which (in your case) would result in a lower performance than a single threaded execution.

Comment: @Luïs You still haven't explained the purpose for using multithreading and insisting that operations be performed in order. Why does it need to be multithreaded and what needs to be performed in a specific order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking how to make a multithreaded loop where the order of execution is guaranteed.  As has been mentioned you can't.  However, if you want to **order the output**, that can be done. Here you've two options

1. Save the results until they are all complete (see pseudocode below):

   - Create a dictionary of inputs to outputs
   - Create a multithreaded loop to process all the inputs and record the outputs
   - Once they are all complete, write the outputs (in order of inputs) to the screen
2. Order the outputs as they are complete.  This is more difficult than #1, but allows you to show results faster.

   - Create a multithreaded loop to process all the inputs
   - Once each thread is complete, show its output, but don't just write it to the screen, insert it into the appropriate spot among all the sorted outputs.

Answer (score 0):

Although you shouldn't use Threads for such sequential uses. What you're asking for is possible.

Here's my example of what you're trying to achieve. It uses multiple thread objects and is guaranteed order. However, you'd probably get better performance just doing it sequentially.

```
    public static void PrintDone()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
    }

    public static void Print(int i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
        Thread.Sleep(10);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            int numCopy = i;
            Thread th = new Thread(() => Print(numCopy));
            threads.Add(th);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            threads[i].Start();
            threads[i].Join();
        }

        PrintDone();
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

So the gist is to create a bunch of threads, then start them all sequentially (there's no way around that part really), and join the main thread directly after. What'll happen is the main thread will start a "subthread" and then wait for it to finish, once it's finished it'll start the next thread, and repeat until it's out of threads in the list.

However, if you're trying to parallelize the printing of the numbers and guarantee the output's order, you're out of luck. Still possible, but the overhead you'll get for trying to maintain the order will defeat the purpose of the parallelization.

Here's an truly parallel version of the code:

```
    public static void PrintDone()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
    }

    public static void Print(int i, int[] threadStatus)
    {
        if(i != 0)
        {
            while(threadStatus[i-1] < 0)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
        }
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        threadStatus[i] = i;
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] threadStatus = Enumerable.Repeat(-1, 10).ToArray();
        List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            int numCopy = i;
            Thread th = new Thread(() => Print(numCopy, threadStatus));
            threads.Add(th);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            threads[i].Start();
        }

        threads[9].Join();
        PrintDone();
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

Since each thread can only write to one part of the int array and reading is atomic, we can use the int array to keep status on all the threads currently running.

This basically means that in any particular "print" thread you can check to see if they are ready to print within the thread, if not you tell them to sleep in a loop so they periodically check their status.